# Nvidia drivers (440, 450) cannot find with GeForce 2080ti (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: driver, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to get Ubuntu 20.04 running on a computer (desktop) with a GeForce 2080Ti and I had no luck with various versions of the nvidia drivers (440 from ppa, latest 450 from nividia website).

However, I could not get it to work :

nvidia-smi --> No devices were found.

In /var/log/Xorg.0.log --> (EE) Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:7:0:0.

dmesg --> NVRM: GPU 0000:07/00.0: RmInitAdapter failed!

Other info that could help:

- I have a GUI when I prime-select intel
- Secure boot is disabled
- nouveau is blacklisted

Thanks for help,

Comment: I continued to look for solutions... I have added mem_encrypt=off but I still get the very same output. Any ideas someone? Could it be a hardware problem?

Comment: What other hardware are you using? I have similar issues, this happens only sometimes after reboot, rebooting again "solves" the issue. (Driver Version: 440.33.01, AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor, ROG Motherboard, not sure about exact chipset version)

Comment: Will check the details later but it is also AMD Ryzen + ROG motherboard... Mine never works though (it is not only "sometimes"). My current step is to perform a windows install to see if the problem is the same (if "yes" I would conclude as a an hardware issue, if "no", I will dig further to find a linux solution)

Comment: Did you solve it

Comment: No, I haven't found the time to perform the windows install. I will keep updated about the results here. If anyone has a suggestion, it is welcome though!

Comment: Interesting, I'm having the same issue also on a Ryzen 3900X but with Asus x570 prime.

Comment: Windows install did not change anything. Now, I am 99% confident it is an hardware issue.